# Typographic styling when writing about UX elements

Tags: typography, interface-design, best-practice

Any thoughts, standards, or good practices on typographical styles to set off UI text in a user manual?

For example, how to style the text of the label on a button in:
"Press the *Submit* button."

Or styling the text of labels and input values:
"Select *Gluten Free* from the dropdown menu. Then enter *I also don't eat soy.* in the *Notes* box."

To be clear -- I'm not asking about designing the UX. I'm asking about typographical styles in a document about the UX.

Comment: At the moment I can't find where I read this, but I seem to remember that Microsoft recommends that when referring to UI text in help, you should **bold** the text. No quotations, no underline, just bold. For an example, check the help in Microsoft Word (F1).

Answer (score 2):

It is a little hard to give an answer to this without pending a little into the opinion factor. But well, what i usually do, and often see others doing as well, is using bold for stuff the user must FIND onscreen/somewhere, while using italics for emphasize and for prompt.

Using your example:

> Select **Gluten Free** from the dropdown menu. Then enter *"I also don't
>   eat soy."* in the **Notes** box.

bold being a *look for* prompt, and italic being an emphasis

Answer (score 1):

Bold and italic are two levels of emphasis on text, you can use bold for things that you want more attention to be drawn at, and italic for stuff that will be noticed mid text, but will not draw much attention to it